# Count items in array by property value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this java-script array:

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq',type=3}, 
            {id:'589',name:'www',type=1}, 
            {id:'45',name:'eee',type=1},
            {id:'567',name:'rrr',type=1},
            {id:'124',name:'qqq',type=2}, 
            {id:'589',name:'ddd',type=2}, 
            {id:'45',name:'qqq',type=1},
            {id:'567',name:'vvv',type=3}]
```

I need to count items in `arr1` array that has type property 1 or 3.

How can I implement it using jQuery?

Comment: `arr1.filter(x => x.type === 1 || x.type === 3).length`

Comment: @haim770 answer the question so i can upvote and the OP can chose it

Comment: I'm sure you've been on SO long enough to at least try something, there are _a lot_ of questions pertaining to the exact question you are asking as well....

Comment: `invalid shorthand property` for @haim770

Comment: this question has lots of duplicates already, OP should remove it (and search before asking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a check and add the value of the comparison.

```js
var array = [{ id: '124', name: 'qqq', type: 3 }, { id: '589', name: 'www', type: 1 }, { id: '45', name: 'eee', type: 1 }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr', type: 1 }, { id: '124', name: 'qqq', type: 2 }, { id: '589', name: 'ddd', type: 2 }, { id: '45', name: 'qqq', type: 1 }, { id: '567', name: 'vvv', type: 3 }],
    count = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        return r + +(a.type === 1 || a.type === 3);
    }, 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var arr1 = [{id:'124',name:'qqq',type=3}, 
            {id:'589',name:'www',type=1}, 
            {id:'45',name:'eee',type=1},
            {id:'567',name:'rrr',type=1},
            {id:'124',name:'qqq',type=2}, 
            {id:'589',name:'ddd',type=2}, 
            {id:'45',name:'qqq',type=1},
            {id:'567',name:'vvv',type=3}];

var count = arr.filter(item => item.type === 3 || item.type === 1).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var len = $.grep(arr1, (o)=> {
    return o.type === 1 || o.type === 3;
}).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```js
var arr1 =[{ id: '124', name: 'qqq', type: 3 }, { id: '589', name: 'www', type: 1 }, { id: '45', name: 'eee', type: 1 }, { id: '567', name: 'rrr', type: 1 }, { id: '124', name: 'qqq', type: 2 }, { id: '589', name: 'ddd', type: 2 }, { id: '45', name: 'qqq', type: 1 }, { id: '567', name: 'vvv', type: 3 }]
                
var count = 0;
arr1.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.type == 1 || e.type == 3 ) 
   {
       count++;
   }
 });

alert(count);
```

will get the count of property type 1 and 3 in Variable "count"

Answer (score 1):

You can call the following function:

```
function count(arr) {   
  return $.grep(arr, function( n ) {
     return ( (n.type === 1) || (n.type === 3) );
  }).length;
}
```

with your array:

```
count(arr1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnSaveClick() {
    for (let i = 0; i < vm.kanoonCourses.length; i++) {
        let cnt = 0;
        cnt += vm.courses.filter(c => c.KanoonCourseTitle == vm.kanoonCourses[i]).length;
        if (cnt > 1) {
            toastr.error("Duplicate course!");
            return;
        }
        else {
           // save data
        }
    }
}
```